# What does the finesse modifier do in FIFA World?

Tags: fifa-world

In the online game FIFA World, when using the "Keyboard and Mouse" control scheme, what does the **"Finesse Modifier"** do?

I have noticed that the cursor shape changes to a cross-hair when I hold A to engage the finesse modifier.  The cursor changes, regardless of whether I am in possession of the ball or not.

In addition to changing the cursor shape, what does the finesse modifier do when you are on offense / possess the ball?  What does the finesse modifier do when you are on defense?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As with all iterations of Fifa, holding the finesse button before you shoot will allow you to place a shot. Usually pretty useful when you are 1 on 1 with the keeper and want to aim where the shot goes more accurately!

If Fifa World is the same as recent iterations of the regular Fifa series, then holding the finesse modifier while not on the ball will send one of your team-mates to put pressure on the player with the ball, which can be pretty handy.

Comment: It's also quite good for placing penalties!

Comment: I am sorry to report that the controls for FIFA World do not coincide with the controls of FIFA 2014 in this regard.  I tried using the "finesse modifier" to call an extra teammate while on defense, and it didn't work.  I can't really say whether or not my shots are more accurate at this point.  I need to perform more research.  In any case, I greatly appreciate your answer.

Comment: The use while defending is more of a recent use in Fifa, but finesse has always applied to being able to place shots!